# Postfix + Dovecot - not receiving mail in vmail directory

Tags: mysql, mail, postfix, dovecot

i have been spending countless hours on this and now i figured id come to the 'internet' for help.

I have installed a new install of postfix + dovecot + mysql.

Right now, i am able to receive email from my one mapped account 'sean@domain.com'
but for some reason all messages get inserted into /var/mail/sean

the expected location is: /var/vmail/domain.com/sean

ill list the key pieces of code ive used to get this working.

**postfix master.cf**

```
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
flags=DRhu user=vmail:mail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}
```

**postfix main.cf**

```
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

**Dovecot 10-mail.conf**

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n
mail_uid = vmail
mail_gid = mail
first_valid_uid = 150
last_valid_uid = 150
```

**Dovecot 10-auth.conf**

```
disable_plaintext_auth = yes
!include auth-sql.conf.ext
```

**Dovecot auth-sql.conf.ext**

```
passdb {
driver = sql
args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
}
userdb {
driver = sql
args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
}
```

**Dovecot dovecot-sql.conf.ext**

```
driver = mysql
connect = host=localhost dbname=mail user=mail password=P@ssw0rd
default_pass_scheme = MD5-CRYPT

password_query = \
SELECT username as user, password, '/var/vmail/%d/%n' as userdb_home, \
'maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n' as userdb_mail, 150 as userdb_uid, 8 as userdb_gid \
FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u' AND active = '1'

user_query = \
SELECT '/var/vmail/%d/%n' as home, 'maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n' as mail, \
150 AS uid, 8 AS gid, concat('dirsize:storage=', quota) AS quota \
FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u' AND active = '1'
```

And that pretty much does it for the config part of what i'm trying to do.

Any ideas of what i'm doing wrong? {  I should be bald by this time tomorrow  :)   }

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are confusing two categories of users. There are the SystemUsers and the VirtualUSers.

If you try to use a systemuser just need to add this line:

```
mailbox_command = /usr/local/libexec/dovecot/deliver
#  or
mailbox_command = /usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver
#  or
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver
#  or wherever it was installed in your system.
```

If you are trying to use a virtualusers, you have to configure them on postfix also.

Something like this:
obs: I will try to use your mysql confs, but not ure if  i will get it right.

```
/etc/postfix/virtual-address-mysql.cf
```

Content:

```
user=mail
password=P@ssw0rd
dbname=mail
hosts=localhost
query=select username as address from mailbox where active = '1' and username = '%s';
```

Look, i might be missing something about your query.

Now postfix is able to know your virtualuser

Need to map it now.

```
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains
virtual_mailbox_maps =  proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual-address-mysql.cf
```

I would go to virtual users, better to manage a db than system users.

You can do also virtual domains and virtual alias

Same logic and the conf is like this:

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/vdomains.cf
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual-alias.cf
```

I guess that its. If need more help i guess you can find in

[Dovecot Wiki](http://wiki2.dovecot.org)

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue and took me some time to dig in.
If anyone has that then is worth to check `/var/log/mail.log` for errors like:

```
postfix/trivial-rewrite[2149]: warning: do not list domain localdomain.co.uk in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
```

I just have removed `localdomain.co.uk` from the `mydestination = line` within the `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file.
This seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem. after a week of nights, found that you may need to create the folder INBOX under /home/username/mail/.imap/INBOX.

That did the trick for me.

System is roundcube / dovecot / postfix / mysql /centos 6.4
Hope I can spare some ones sanity!!

Paul.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your "virtual_mailbox_map.cnf" file (may have different name) 
it should be something like this

```
hosts = 127.0.0.1
user = postfix
password = password
dbname = postfix
query = SELECT CONCAT(domain, '/', maildir) FROM mailbox WHERE username='%s' AND active = 1
```

The fix in a query because in all manuals that I saw they use something like this

```
query = SELECT maildir FROM mailbox WHERE username='%s' AND active = 1
```